# background image not stretched properly

Tags: html, css

The page can be viewed live here: http://tmstaging.cloudapp.net:88/en/my/news/sample-great-food-and-tasty-celebrities-with-astro-bella-new-show-taste-selebriti

The problem is on the first section of the two-column carousel. I've checked my css that if I removed this line of code:

```
  background-position: center center !important;
```

From the class below :

```
  .promo-content .banner .slides > li
```

The background images would show properly. But I'm not sure if that's an effective solution. Also when resize to tablet sizes - the right column is shorter than the left column. How do I maintain for these two columns to be the same height?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think its fine to remove `background-position` as it is making `background-size` look very odd. And if you remove `background-position`, then there would not be any need of `important` in `background-size`. Please don't use `important` excessively as it will confuse you a lot when project size expands; and you would have to remember the places where `important` is used.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is best for you.**

```
.promo-content .banner .slides > li {
      min-height: 385px;
      background-position: center center !important;
      background-size: auto 100% !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat !important; }
```